# Using a value in a class to set equal to a new value without changing previous value c++

Tags: c++

I am using a class structure for rational numbers. I'm trying to essentially use the r2 values for the num and den (numerator and denominator) and have them be negative and equal to r3. While r3.output(cout, "r3") should output
r3: 4/1.

Current output of code (when I remove the r3):
r1: 10/3
r2 = -4/1

I cannot grasp how to essentially go back in class data to set the values of r3 to be equal to the values of negative r2. I have to use the int main commands, so those can not be changed.

Thank you, this is my first real class, so it will be messy. Please ignore the other operands, I have yet to get to those.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class rational {
    int num,den,nummod,denmod;
public:
    rational (int,int); //Constructor
    int gcd (int n1 ,int n2); //Finds GCD
    int simplified(int x, int y,int z); //Simplifies the fraction
    //IO
    int input();
    void output(ostream& y, string label); //Outputs the fraction

    //Expressions
    int neg(void);

    rational &sub();
    rational &add();
    rational &mul();
    rational &div();

};

rational::rational(int x,int y)
{
    if(y == 0) //make it throw a cerr error and exit with -1.
    {
        cout<<"0 in denominator error"<<'\n';
        return;
    }
    int z = gcd(x,y);
    simplified(x,y,z); //Gets the simplified numerator and denominator
    return;
}
int rational::simplified(int x, int y, int z) {
    num = x/z;
    den = y/z;
    return 1;
}

int rational::gcd(int n1, int n2) { //Code provided by the homework
    int tmp;
    while (n2 != 0) {
        tmp = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = tmp % n2;
    }
}

void rational::output(ostream &y, string label) {
    if(cout)
    {
        string fraction = to_string(num) + "/" + to_string(den);
        cout<<label<<": "<<fraction<<'\n';
        return;
    }
    //if()
    //{
    //    return;
    //}
}

int rational::neg(void) {r2.neg();
    int temp;
    if (num < 0) {
        num =num * -1;
    }
    if (den < 0) {
        den =den * -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    rational r1(10, 3);
    rational r2(8, -2);

    r1.output(cout, "r1");
    r2.output(cout, "r2");
    rational r3 = r2.neg();  //This is the error
    r3.output(cout, "r3");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given the way you're using this neg function, it should return a new rational instance, rather than an int.

Comment: The output in the `gcd` function will not happen, as you `return` before it. Same with `r2.neg();`, that statement also will not happen.

Comment: And in the `output` function, what is the purpose of the `y` argument if you don't use it? And I don't see the need for the temporary `fraction` variable in that function, it could all be done through the normal stream output operator `<<`.

Comment: Also, you do `r2.output(cout, "r3");`, but that "label" (`"r3"`) is misleading as it's the  `r2` object that is used for the output.

Comment: Oh and what *is* e.g. `r2` in some of your functions? You seem to have forgotten some lessons about scoping. The code you show won't build, much less run and produce the output you claim. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: It looks like you need to review the introductions to variables, functions, and objects in your C++ book.

Comment: The output in the gcd function works like it's supposed to. Everything works fine, I just cannot get the neg() function to fully work. The y is for a later date and was *given* by the homework assignment so I cannot change that. For that part, I need it to know if y is cout or ofs, to either print or output to a file, something which I am still ensure how to do. That r2.output(cout, "r3"); was not supposed to be there, I just copied that in wrong, my bad.

Comment: `rational rational::neg() { rational r; r.num = -num; r.den = -den; return r; }`?

Comment: This worked. I just wasn't aware I could establish a rational r in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize r3. It probably should be throwing a warning (maybe with the -Wextra g++ flag or something of that ilk). As Botje mentioned, one option would be to code neg() as a constructor for a Rational object that takes a reference to a Rational object being negated.

Another option is to code neg() as a void function, that simply negates the list that it was called on (e.g. `r2.neg()` to negate r2). This would still require a way of making r3 a copy of r2.

Lastly, the `this->` in you neg() function is unnecessary as the scope resolution operator `rational::` puts you in the scope where you need to be to access that (member function)

Comment: Sadly I cannot initialize r3 as the entire main is what I have to go from. I cannot edit it anyway. I did the void function for the neg(), how would I make the copy from r2 to r3? The main thing here is to ensure r2 is not overwritten with r3. 
Thank you

Comment: well in main r1 and r2 are initialized by constructors. as other commenters mentioned. if you can't change this main at all then neg is going to have to return a Rational object. Look up copy constructors.
Also probably a copy paste error but the first thing that happens when you enter neg is you call neg again.. If that ran it'd loop until recursion stack overflow

Comment: Yes, that was a copy paste error even though it wasn't in my source code. Anyways, I updated the original post to fix that. How would I make it return a rational object? I tried but it still gave me a conversion to non scalar type error. Thanks

Comment: check out this article on copy constructors:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm